# Typescript bind issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, typescript

I'm trying to port this function from prototype to jquery in typescript:

```
    onFailure: function(xhr) {
    // Get options
    var opts = this;

    // Show result
    var msgBox = opts.msgBox ? opts.msgBox : opts.client.options.msgBox;  
    if (msgBox && !opts.onFailure) {
        msgBox.showError('Communicatie fout.');
    }

    // Handle onFailure callback
    if (opts.onFailure) {
        opts.onFailure.bind(opts.client)(xhr);
    }
    else if (opts.options && opts.options.onFailure) {
        opts.options.onFailure.bind(opts.client)(xhr);
    }

    // Fire event
    opts.client.failureCb.fire('failure');
},
```

This is the ported code:

```
        onFailure(xhr){
            // Get options
            var opts = this;

            // Show result
            var msgBox = opts.msgBox ? opts.msgBox : opts.client.options.msgBox;
            if (msgBox && !opts.onFailure) {
                msgBox.showError('Communicatie fout.');
            }

            // Handle onFailure callback
            if (opts.onFailure) {
                opts.onFailure(opts.client)(xhr);
            }
            else if (opts.options && opts.options.onFailure) {
                opts.options.onFailure.bind(opts.client)(xhr);
            }

            // Fire event
            opts.client.failureCb.fire('failure');
        }
```

As you see it's not much different. The problem however comes from the typescript compiler:

> error TS2094: The property 'bind' does not exist on value of type 'null'

How should this be correctly ported to jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a full example? I can't fit this example into context - if I was using jQuery AJAX I would expect to use `.error( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)` to handle AJAX failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason why that would happen is because typescript has inferred the type based on what you wrote:

```
var opts = {
    options:{
        onFailure: null
    }
} 

// The property 'bind' does not exist on value of type 'null'
opts.options.onFailure.bind();
```

You can overwrite this behavior by explicitly typing the variable to be `any`:

```
var opts:any = {
    options:{
        onFailure: null
    }
} 

// no more error
opts.options.onFailure.bind();
```

This will remove the compile error, but I suspect this compile error might be pointing to a valid logic error in your code.